# How to install COCO PythonAPI in python3

Tags: python, mscoco

It seems the [COCO PythonAPI](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi) only support python2. But peoples do use it in python3 environment.

I tried possible methods to install it, like

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
python3 setup.py install
```

But `python3 setup.py install` will fail due to `coco.py` and `cocoeval.py` containning python2 print function.

Update: solved by updating the [COCO PythonAPI](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi) project. Leave this question for people facing the same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Use git clone to clone the folder into your drive. In this case, it should be `git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git`
2. Use terminal to enter the directory, or open a terminal inside the directory
3. Type in `2to3 . -w`. Note that you might have to install a package to get 2to3. It is an elegant tool to convert code from Python2 to Python3; this code converts all .py files from Python2-compatible to Python3-compatible
4. Use terminal to navigate to the setup folder
5. Type in `python3 setup.py install`

This should help you install COCO or any package intended for Python2, and run the package using Python3. Cheers!

Comment: Is this step mandatory? I just installed cocoapi without doing that `2to3` conversion first, and I didn't get any error from the installation.

Comment: @avazula If it worked for you without the conversion, that's great! What version of Python are you using? Do you use Anaconda for your environment?

Comment: I'm not using any virtual environment (now I feel stupid for not doing it). My Python version is 3.5.2. I just cloned the repo & launched the setup with python3 & everything seemed fine.

Comment: You're missing one step to make it work. Before installing, you need to specify Python 3 source in Cython's setup.py, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116368/6374637).

Answer (score 7):

I have completed it with a simple step

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI"
```

** before that you need to install Visual C++ 2015 build tools on your path

[image]

Answer (score 5):

#### Install

1. Instead of the official version (which has issues with python 3) use an [alternative one](https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi). Install it on your local machine, *globally* (i.e., outside any virtual environment). You can do this by:

   `pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI`
2. Check if it is installed globally:

   `pip freeze | grep "pycocotools"`

You should see something like `pycocotools==2.0.0` in your output.

3. Now, inside your virtual-env (conda or whatever), first install `numpy` and `cython` (and maybe `setuptools` if it's not installed) using *pip*, and then:

   `pip install pycocotools`

#### Verify

Inside your project, import (for example) `from pycocotools import mask as mask` and then `print(mask.__author__)`. This should print out the author's name, which is *tsungyi*.

#### Where Is It?

The installed package, like any other packages that are locally installed inside a virtual-env using *pip*, will go to *External Libraries* of your project, under *site-packages*. That means it is now part of your virtual-env and not part of your project. So, other users who may want to use your code, must repeat this installation on their virtual-env as well.

---

**Troubleshooting:**

The main source of confusion is that either **you did not install the required packages** before installing cocoapi, or **you did install the required packages but for a different python version**. And when you want to check if something is installed, you may check with, for instance, python**3.6** and see that it exists, but you are actually running all your commands with python**3.7**. So suppose you are using **python3.7**. You need to make sure that:

1. `python -V` gives you *python3.7* and NOT other version, and `pip -V` gives you `pip 19.2.3 from /home/<USER>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python3.7)`, that actually matches with your default python version. If this is not the case, you can change your default python using `sudo update-alternatives --config python`, and following the one-step instruction.
2. All the required packages are installed using the right *python* or *pip* version. You can check this using `pip` and `pip3` to stop any differences that may cause an issue: 
   `pip freeze | grep "<SUBSTRING-NAME-OF-PACKAGE>"` or `pip show <PACKAGE-NAME>` for more recent versions of *pip*.
3. To install the required packages, after you made sure about (1), you need to run:
   `sudo apt install python-setuptools python3.7-dev python3-wheel build-essential` and `pip install numpy cython matplotlib`

---

**Environment:**
The above steps were tested on *Ubuntu 18.4*, *python 3.6.8*, *pip 19.0.3*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggling building pycocotools on Ubuntu 20.04 and python3.7
try this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3.7-dev
python3.7 -m pip install pycocotools>=2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are alternative versions of the cocoapi that you can download and use too (I'm using python 3.5). Here's a solution that you might want to try out: 
[How to download and use object detection datasets (e.g. coco or pascal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807254/how-to-download-and-use-object-detection-datasets-e-g-coco-or-pascal/52325290#52325290)

Answer (score 0):

here's how i did successfully! (the reason is the gcc version)

1. install the dependencies: cython (pip install cython),  opencv (pip install opencv-python)
2. check the gcc version by this command: gcc --version
3. your output will be like this 'Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:
   sudo apt install gcc
   '
4. Type the below commands to install the gcc:
   sudo apt update

   sudo apt install build-essential

   sudo apt-get install manpages-dev
5. now check again the gcc version(step2)
   if you get below output

   'gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
   Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.'
6. now run the code for pycocotools installations:

   pip install "git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI"
7. finally wait check if the installation is successful :

   'Successfully installed pycocotools-2.0'