# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS install cocoapi

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

OS：Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Python Environment = 3.6.8 (System default version)

I followed [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#coco-api-installation) to install cocoapi.

However, it shows the error below:

```
ubuntu:~/cocoapi-master/PythonAPI$ make
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I have already installed the needed dependencies mentioned in objection_detection/g3doc/installation.md.

I have also installed Cython and Numpy.

Could somebody help me fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

I run this code

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

It doesn't show error.

However, when I tried to run a Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py, it shows error again.

Command line:

```
ubuntu:~/PycharmProjects/PedestrianDetection$ python object_detection/model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=pretrained/pipeline.config --model_dir=train --num_train_steps=1000 --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 --alsologtostderr
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 26, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib
  File "/home/yantong/PycharmProjects/PedestrianDetection/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 28, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "/home/yantong/PycharmProjects/PedestrianDetection/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 28, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
  File "/home/yantong/PycharmProjects/PedestrianDetection/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_tools
  File "/home/yantong/PycharmProjects/PedestrianDetection/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pycocotools import coco
  File "/home/yantong/PycharmProjects/PedestrianDetection/pycocotools/coco.py", line 55, in <module>
    from . import mask as maskUtils
  File "/home/yantong/PycharmProjects/PedestrianDetection/pycocotools/mask.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pycocotools._mask as _mask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycocotools._mask'
```

Under ~/PycharmProjects/PedestrianDetection/pycocotools, I have

```
cocoeval.py      coco.py      __init__.py  mask.py    __pycache__
cocoeval.py.bak  coco.py.bak  _mask.c      _mask.pyx
```

I'm wondering why it shows No module named 'pycocotools._mask' as well.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311195/how-to-install-coco-pythonapi-in-python3

Comment: @JoeA I have already tried, but still doesn't work.

Comment: What if you clone the GIT repo then run python PythonAPI/setup.py build_ext install or python3 whichever works

Comment: @JoeA I edited my post.  I could `Make` it by prompting `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`. However, it still shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycocotools._mask'. Does that matter with pycocotools installation?

Comment: It seems important according to the GitHub repo you can run the following : pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI           The repo is here: https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi#egg=pycocotools%5E&subdirectory=PythonAPI

Comment: @JoeA Succeeded! Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. According to @Joe A 's guidance, finally `make` pycocotools by prompting:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI
```

It will be installed in the Ubuntu path `/home/USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

2. Enter the path `/home/USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Using Terminal to cd the path above.

NOTICE: USERNAME means your account name on Ubuntu (for me is yantong), replace it with yours.

3. Copy the downloaded pycocotools from the Step1-2 to your code package.

```
cp -r pycocotools YOUR_PACKAGE_PATH
```

NOTICE: You'd better replace YOUR_PACKAGE_PATH with your package's absolute path.

4. Test
   Test by open a Python3 script and prompt:

```
from pycocotools.coco import COCO
from pycocotools import mask as maskUtils
```

Press ENTER, if not with error, congrats!

Comment: Happy to help! Congrats on solving it!

Comment: In CoLab, this library is installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the gcc version or installations in your system, follow this if the above solutions fail.

here's how I did it successfully! (the reason is the gcc version)

1. install the dependencies: cython (pip install python),  opencv (`pip install opencv-python`)
2. check the gcc version by this command: gcc --version
3. your output will be like this 'Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:
   sudo apt install gcc
   '
4. Type the below commands to install the gcc:
   `sudo apt update`

   `sudo apt install build-essential`

   `sudo apt-get install manpages-dev`
5. now check again the gcc version(step2)
   if you get below output

   'gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
   Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.'
6. now run the code for pycocotools installations:

   `pip install "git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI"`
7. finally wait to check if the installation is successful :

   'Successfully installed pycocotools-2.0'