# how to import coco_utils and coco_eval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

To get a PyTorch script to work, I need to be able to do:

```
import coco_utils
import coco_eval
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.

Based on this post:

[How to install COCO PythonAPI in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311195/how-to-install-coco-pythonapi-in-python3)

I've done the following so far:

```
cd ~

git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git

cd cocoapi/PythonAPI

# open Makefile in gedit, change the two instances of "python" to "python3"

python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace

sudo python3 setup.py install
```

now this works:

```
import pycocotools
```

but these still don't:

```
import coco_utils
import coco_eval
```

How can I import `coco_utils` and `coco_eval` ??

Answer (score 4):

`coco_utils.py` and `coco_eval.py` must be the name of the files that should be in the repository you're trying to use.

Possibly you're looking for the object detection reference training scripts provided in the [`detection`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/master/references/detection) (`vision/references/detection/`) module of torchvision.