# What are differences between Cython's language_level 3 and 3str?

Tags: python, cython

In the upcoming Cython 3.0 version, `3str` language_level (which was introduced with [Cython 0.29](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/changes.html#id28)) becomes the new default instead of the current default `2`, i.e. if language_level is not set ([how to set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34603628/5769463)), we get the following warning:

> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str'
>   for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File:
>   /home/ed/mygithub/cython/foo.pyx   tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd,
>   full_module_name)

But what are the differences between `3str` and `3` language levels and for which code will there be differences in the behavior of modules compiled with `3str` and `3` language levels?

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR:** `3str` does not assume that string literals are unicode under Python2.x making migration from Python2.x to Python3 easier.

Not a complete answer because I don't know the code to highlight the differences and this still leaves room for questions, but this may be useful, [Whats new in cython 0.29](http://blog.behnel.de/posts/whats-new-in-cython-029.html):

> **A new language-level**'
>
> Cython 0.29 supports a new setting for the `language_level` directive, `language_level=3str`, which will become the new default language level in Cython 3.0. We already added it now, so that users can opt in and benefit from it right away, and already prepare their code for the coming change. It's an "in between" kind of setting, which **enables all the nice Python 3 goodies that are not syntax compatible with Python 2.x, but without requiring all unprefixed string literals to become Unicode strings when the compiled code runs in Python 2.x**. This was one of the biggest problems in the general Py3 migration. And in the context of Cython's integration with C code, it got in the way of our users even a bit more than it would in Python code. Our goals are to make it easy for new users who come from Python 3 to compile their code with Cython and to allow existing (Cython/Python 2) code bases to make use of the benefits before they can make a 100% switch.

Also noted by [Debian's manpage for cython](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/cython/cython.1.en.html):

> `--embed[=<method_name>]` Generate a main() function that embeds the Python interpreter.
> `-2` Compile based on Python-2 syntax and code semantics.
> `-3` Compile based on Python-3 syntax and code semantics.
> `--3str` Compile based on Python-3 syntax and code semantics without assuming unicode by default for string literals under Python 2.

Lastly noted by [cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html):

> The `3str` option enables Python 3 semantics but does not change the `str` type and unprefixed string literals to `unicode` when the compiled code runs in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 4):

`language_level` is used to indicate in which Python-version the pyx-file is written. Thus for `language_level=3` the resulting behavior of the pyx-code is as if it were executed in Python3 even when the resulting extension is run with Python2 (see a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54900723/5769463)).

Language level `3str` means "Python3 semantics, but with str literals (also in Python2.7)" - thus `str` in the name. What are exactly the consequences?

**Python3:** When built in/for Python3 there are no differences between level `3` and level `3str`.

In Python3, `str` is `unicode`, so the type of

```
# foo.pyx
def test():
   return type("aaa")
```

will stay the same (`str`) for `language_level=3` and `language_level=3str`.

**Python2:** The situation is different when built with/for Python2. With `language_level=3` the result of the above `test`-function will be `unicode` and with `language_level=3str` the result will be `str` (which is bytes in Python2). But also for Python2, in all other cases, `3` and `3str` have the same behavior.

---

It would be a mistake to think, that

```
cdef char *c_string = "some string"
```

would fail to build with `language_level=3` (and build successfuly with `3str` for Python2, as "some string" were `bytes`), because `"some string"` is unicode and unicode literals can be only to coerced only to `Py_UNICODE*`.

The literal on the righthand-side isn't a Python-object to begin with, but just a C-string in the generated C-code.