# Python3 Cython: function __annotation__ yields unicode instead of str

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, cython

In my code base, I use `Cython` to create shared object files from my modules. When I try to access the function `__annotations__`, I get the different behavior when I use Cython and when I do not, and I am wondering why this is the case:

#### Minimal example:

I tried to produce a minimal reproducable example and came up with the following two files `main.py` and `setup.py` that I create within the same directory. Requirements: `pip install Cython setuptools`.

**main.py**

```py
import setup

def test(name: str): pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(test.__annotations__, setup.test.__annotations__)
```

**Setup.py**

```py
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import setup, Extension

def test(name: str): pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(python_requires='>=3.6', ext_modules=cythonize([Extension('setup', ['setup.py']), ], language_level="3"))
```

Execution

```sh
python main.py
> {'name': <class 'str'>}
> {'name': <class 'str'>}

python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python main.py
> {'name': <class 'str'>}
> {'name': 'unicode'}
```

I would have expected the `__annotations__` to yield `str` also when using the shared object files, but it yields `unicode` instead. Why is this the case?

I use `Python 3.9.2` and `Cython version 0.29.21`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really more of a bug report than a question, so probably should be on the Cython bug tracker instead of here. Fortunately [something similar already is reported](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1370).

There's a few things going on here:

1. Cython still aims to support Python 2.7. That means that the code it generates has to work on both. While annotations are a Py3 feature, the code to get the name is general and used in a number of places. It therefore picks `unicode` rather than `str` for strings that it knows are definitely unicode to ensure that both are supported.
2. Your choice of `language_level=3` also affects it - strings are unicode whether or not it's running in Python 2 or 3. If you use [`language_level=3str`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415446/what-are-differences-between-cythons-language-level-3-and-3str) it uses "native" strings instead and thus returns `str` (i.e. `bytes` on Py2, `unicode` on Py3).
3. At least on Cython 3 (alpha, at the moment), Cython implements [PEP-563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/), and thus the annotations are always stored as strings rather than types - thus you get `'unicode'` rather than `<class 'unicode'>`. This reflects the future behaviour of Python. I didn't think this change was in Cython 0.29.x so I'm a little surprised that you see it here - it's probably a shortcut that's accidentally "right" in this case.

The forthcoming Cython 3 release is aiming to improve treatments of annotations (and other introspection features) to be closer to Python behaviour. The 0.29 branch probably won't see changes to this.