# python print() output tuple after being CPython compiled into .so

Tags: python, printing, shared-libraries, cpython

The python print() will only print its arguments like a tuple after this .py is CPython-compiled into a .so and being imported. How can it behave like it is a normal py file?

The scenarios is like this. Here is a function `output()` defined in mod4.py:

```
def output(a, b):
    print(a, b, str(a)+str(b))
```

I use following `main.py` to call `output()`:

```
import mod4
mod4.output(2, 3)
```

the output will be like:

```
2 3 23
```

Then I compile mod4.py using CPython, by editing a setup.py like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name="mod4.app", ext_modules=cythonize("mod4.py"))
```

and execute `python setup.up build_ext --inplace` in command line, which in turn generates `mod4.cpython-37m-darwin.so`. Then `main.py` will output like:

```
(2, 3, '23')
```

it looks just like a tuple of the arguments of print().

The version of python is 3.7.4,

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
```

How can I get `output()` in .so outputs just like it in .py?

Comment: I would guess that the compiled version is based on python2.

Comment: I am using python 3.7.4 generally in my own environment. How to tell specifically what version is used by the compiled version?

Comment: Well, what is the command line which produces your .so? Surely a —version option will tell you.

Comment: I edited OP with details of compiling the .so and python version. thanks!

Comment: You need to provide language level 3 to cythonize, otherwise python2 syntax is assumed. When you compile the must be a warning telling you that

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your advice, @quamrana and @ead. With your hints and a reference to [How to specify Python 3 source in Cython's setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603628/how-to-specify-python-3-source-in-cythons-setup-py), I edited the setup.py like following (added **language_level="3"** in cythonize() call):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name="mod4.app", ext_modules=cythonize("mod4.py", language_level="3"))
```

and the output becomes what I expect.